# CakePHP Get url Parameter, --"undefined index", anyway to grab if present and not cause error if its not?

Tags: php, cakephp

Using this:

```
$vertical = $this->params['url']['vertical'];
```

Basically want to grab the parameter if its there, and not cause an error if it isn't (it gives undefined index if it isn't provided).

The reason I need to do this is because I am updating my backend before the person I'm working with updates their end.  And I want it to be ready when they do.

Have had to do this a few times, so decided I would finally ask and see if anyone can help!

Using CakePHP 2.3.1

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 2.x (>= 2.3) you would simply do:

```
$vertical = $this->request->query('vertical');
```

It is always a good idea to read the documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters

Comment: Is this the 'proper' way to do things?  (is $params['url'] deprecated?  Googled and wasn't clear.. Thanks for your help!  It works :)

Comment: The part in the docu also states that.